# Java - KeyListener multiple button presses

Tags: java, awt, 2d, controls, keylistener

I hope I can describe my problem in the right way. I am programming a simple Twin-Stick Shooter at the moment so I implemented a KeyInputHandler calss that implements KeyListener. But when the player pressed 2 buttons at the same time I ran into a problem. It took always a second before the player actually moves. As far as I know that is because of the key repeat. I might be wrong. I googled a bit and found a possible solution here:
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/51623/smoother-controls?rq=1
The people suggested to not change the x- and y-velocity of the player on key press but instead flag the direction when the player presses a certain button and handle the movement in a different method. So I created the boolean variables and activated them when the button is pressed:

```
public class KeyInputHandler implements KeyListener{

private Game game;
// checks if A key is down
public boolean left_key_down = false;
// checks if D key is down
public boolean right_key_down = false;
// checks if W key is down
public boolean up_key_down = false;
// checks if S key is down
public boolean down_key_down = false;

public KeyInputHandler(Game game) {
    this.game = game;
}

public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keys = e.getKeyCode();

    if (keys == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        right_key_down = true;
    } else if (keys == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        left_key_down = true;
    } else if (keys == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        up_key_down = true;
    } else if (keys == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        down_key_down = true;
    }
}

public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int keys = e.getKeyCode();

    if (keys == KeyEvent.VK_D) {
        right_key_down = false;
    } else if (keys == KeyEvent.VK_A) {
        left_key_down = false;
    } else if (keys == KeyEvent.VK_W) {
        up_key_down = false;
    } else if (keys == KeyEvent.VK_S) {
        down_key_down = false;
    }
}

public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

}

public void tick() {

    if (left_key_down) {
        game.p.setVelX(-1);
    } else if (right_key_down) {
        game.p.setVelX(1);
    } else if (up_key_down) {
        game.p.setVelY(-1);
    } else if (down_key_down) {
        game.p.setVelY(1);
    } else {
        game.p.setVelY(0);
        game.p.setVelX(0);
    }
}
}
```

(The tick() method is called in the main game loop)

The problem is now that there is no delay anymore (yay), but the things get strange when I press 2 buttons together. Example:

1. I press the left Button
2. I press the down Button
3. I let the down Button go -> Objects still goes down-left
4. I press up -> Object goes up-left

But when I hold Right and then als hold Down it is just moving down.

I also checked the boolean variables and they are getting refreshed correctly. 
This is kinda weird and I am not really sure how to handle this and what exactly is causing this behaviour. I have the assumption that it has something to do with the order in which the cooleans are checked. Maybe someon can help me on this matter. I would greatly appreciate it. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem why things are getting strange in multiple key presses together is that you are using if else's in checking the booleans. Separete all the boolean checks in tick() to own individual ifs. If any one of the buttons are being pressed constantly, the code never goes to the last else-block where VelX and VelY are reset to zero.

Change the code in tick method to something like this:

```
//Set 'velocity' to zero first
game.p.setVelY(0);
game.p.setVelX(0);

if (left_key_down) {
    game.p.setVelX(-1);
} 
if (right_key_down) {
    game.p.setVelX(1);
} 
if (up_key_down) {
    game.p.setVelY(-1);
} 
if (down_key_down) {
    game.p.setVelY(1);
}
```

Comment: Works like a charm. Yeah that else-if parts where the problem. Didn't realize this. Thank you :)