# Multiple Keyboard Inputs Java

Tags: java, keyboard-events

Im working on a space invaders type game and I have a keyboard controller class but the problem is if I want to move my player I can shoot at the same time, how can I change my controller to fix this?

Key Pressed

```
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for(int i = 0; i<handler.object.size(); i++) {
        gameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId()==ObjectID.Player){
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(-5);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_W) tempObject.setVelY(-10);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_S) tempObject.setVelY(10);
        }
        if(tempObject.getId()==ObjectID.Player && key == KeyEvent.VK_SPACE){
            CurrentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

            if(NextShootTime<CurrentTime){
                handler.addObject(new Bullet(tempObject.getX()+40, tempObject.getY()-20,0, ObjectID.Bullet));
                handler.addObject(new Bullet(tempObject.getX()+30, tempObject.getY()-20,1, ObjectID.Bullet));
                handler.addObject(new Bullet(tempObject.getX()+50, tempObject.getY()-20,2, ObjectID.Bullet));
                NextShootTime = CurrentTime+ShootDelay;
            }
        }

        if(tempObject.getId()==ObjectID.Bullet){
            tempObject.setVelY(-5f);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_K) {
                handler.removeObject(tempObject);
            }
        }
    }

    if(key == KeyEvent.VK_ESCAPE ) {
        System.exit(0);
    }
}
```

Key Released

```
public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
    int key = e.getKeyCode();

    for(int i = 0; i<handler.object.size(); i++) {
        gameObject tempObject = handler.object.get(i);

        if(tempObject.getId()==ObjectID.Player){
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_D) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_A) tempObject.setVelX(0);
            if(key ==KeyEvent.VK_W) tempObject.setVelY(0);
            if(key ==KeyEvent.VK_S) tempObject.setVelY(0);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Here is a similar problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26947311/java-keylistener-multiple-button-presses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do not calculate the speed, acceleration and direction in the `KeyEvent`. You should do that in your GameLoop. You can memorize the keystrokes in the KeyEvent and then process them in the GameLoop.

You could query the KeyEvents as follows.

```
private final BitSet keys = new BitSet();

addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        keys.set(e.getKeyCode());
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
         keys.clear(e.getKeyCode());
    }
});
```

In your GameLoop you can use `keys.get(keyCode)` to query whether one or more keys are pressed.